# Correct Syntax for accessing this array

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

[image]I have a View controller, with a tableview inside of it. I have a navigation button called "create". After the user has filled in a couple textfields and selected a cells from the UITableview i want the create button to create a parse object with the selected and inputed information.

I have these arrays..

```
 var name = [String]()
 var address = [String]()

var theseItems:[String] = []  //globalArray
```

im appending the selected cells to "theseItems" array.

```
 //i have already queried and added what i wanted, to the name and address array..so they are filled with information.


     didSelectRowAtIndexPath  {
    self.theseItems.append(name[indexPath.row] as String)
    self.theseItems.append(address[indexPath.row] as String)
```

now with the create Button i want to create an object from this information but am having a hard time accessing the selected cell index path in the button...

```
    @IBAction func createButton(sender: AnyObject) {

let thisObject = PFObject(className:"thisObject")
thisObject["name"] = name.text
thisObject["address"] = address.text
thisObject["selectedCell"] = theseItems(name[indexPath.row]) 
thisObject["selectedCell2"] = theseItems(address[indexPath.row])
//error** unresolved identifier "indexPath"
```

I'm not sure the correct way to access the array with a cells information.. to save it to parse. thanks in advance!

```
thisObject.saveEventually()
```

Comment: By convention, variables that refer to a collection of items, such as an array of names or addresses should be pluralized. Change `name` to `names` and `address` to `addresses`.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the index paths of the currently selected cells by calling the `indexPathsForSelectedRows()` method on the table view (or `indexPathForSelectedRow()` if constrained to a single selection at one time).

Comment: how do i access that within the IBAction Button? as far as calling that function within it.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access a an array position from text, but text is a textField, not an array

Comment: the items I'm selecting are already queried from parse and I'm just trying to append them to the theseItems array and create another object from the ones selected...i understand the text part, I'm not adding those to the theseItems array.